# SQL subqueries what has the best performance

Tags: sql, performance, subquery, exists, in-clause

I'm having a question about this SQL query:

```
 SELECT class
 FROM Ships
 WHERE name IN (SELECT ship
                FROM Outcomes
                WHERE result = ’sunk’);
```

Can I write in the subquery `SELECT * From Outcomes` or do I always need to `select` a `row`?

And what query has the best performance then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put * in this subquery. The best way to do it is:

```
SELECT class
  FROM Ships s
 WHERE exists
     (
        select 1 
          from Outcomes o
        where s.name = o.ship
          and result = ’sunk’
       )
```

Answer (score 2):

For performance point of view use this query

```
 select class 
 FROM Ships 
 join outcomes on ships.name=outcomes.ship
 and result like 'sunk'
```

Comment: if he's using SQL-Server this could be less performant. In MySQL is the same

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to state the column you are selecting.

I would recommend a join instead

```
 seLECT class 
 FROM Ships 
     inner join outcomes
     on ships.name=outcomes.ship
    WHERE result = ’sunk’
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to select a single column, as you have done in your SQL example.

Its also worth noting that wildcard `*` is bad for performance as the server will then need to do some extra work to work out what all the columns are, as you have not explicitly stated.

If you want to include more than one column to be compared in the `IN` then I would suggest using a `UNION` in your sub-query:

```
SELECT class
     FROM Ships
     WHERE name IN
       (SELECT ship
        FROM Outcomes
        WHERE result = ’sunk’
        UNION
        SELECT secondColumn
        FROM Outcomes
        WHERE result = ’sunk’        
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `In`, so you need only one `row` to compare it to name.
In this particular case, you can use a Join as an alternative.
In `MySQL` are equally performant, but [in SQL-Server In is more performant than Join](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/).
So, you you will have to return only one row in this case.

In case you use a `subquery` in a `inner join`, you could use `*`, but for readability is better to return the fields you will use.
This example, will be

```
select (fields..)
from yourTable
inner join (select fields from yourTable2) T2 on ConditionOfJoining

select (fields..)
from yourTable
inner join (select * from yourTable2) T2 on ConditionOfJoining
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always try to avoid to use *. Even better would be never to use the *.

But in your query you MUST state the column.

Comment: I agree with Asif below 

select class  
 FROM Ships  
 join outcomes on ships.name=outcomes.ship 
 and result like 'sunk'

But your database design might even be better when you have a foreign key in your "outcomes" table that is linked to the id of your "ships" table, instead of using the name. (Uses less storage, and prevents typos)

SELECT class  
FROM Ships  
     INNER JOIN outcomes ON ships.Id = outcomes.shipId and result = ’sunk’